# flash animation alternative

Tags: html, flash, animation

I have clients that ask for animations that will work on ipad. For that it would have to be non flash. They will also want the animations to work in IE. My question is, is there a best practice for this? I am assuming using flash and export with flash html5 export. Sniff out canvas capability and provide a fallback for IE6/7/8 to flash. The reason is its much faster to build complex character animations with the flash IDE timeline and css3 is better performance. Or is it best practice to build everything in something with javascript, like greensock, and build it one timed function after another. Or is there something that will convert flash or canvas animations to javascript for IE users who don't have flash installed and don't support canvas?

Comment: Depends on your preference. You can use css3 or JavaScript, and its easier to use jQuery for your JavaScript animations if you decide to use JavaScript.

Comment: But using css3 is not going to work on IE. Thats a huge chunk of viewing population. There should be a "best practice" to which one and what is easier/ faster to animate with.

Comment: It really depends on the animation. Is it moving text/html like things around, or is it's more complex SVG-like animation?

Comment: So different technology based on the animation? I was hoping there was a standard that was used for simple animations that can also accomodate complex SVG. Aren't there still big issues regardless of the animation, such as IE6,7,8 does not support canvas and that is still a huge population.

Comment: I would use jQuery animations, it works with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adobe Edge.

http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/

Looks very impressive.